# Dirichlet problem in unbounded domain

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations, potential-theory

In bounded domains of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Dirichlet problem has a unique solution:
the equation $\triangle u=0$ with prescribed boundary value has a unique solution. This is not true if the domain is unbounded.

Is there any result for existence and uniqueness for unbounded domains under further assumptions on the domain and the function? If there is a reference where this question is treated it would be of help.

Comment: the statement for bounded domains is not true - try find a harmonic function in the punctured disc that goes to zero on the unit circle and to $1$ at the origin; one needs topological restrictions on the domain; Conway book on complex analysis (volume 1 chapter 10) has a very good treatment of the Dirichlet problem and then volume 2 has a deeper treatment

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! I meant simply connected domains. Maybe there is a simple proof in such case.

Comment: the standard proof uses subharmonic functions and the Perron method - since boundaries can be very complicated even for simply connected domains, one needs that in general; for smooth boundary, classical tools work of course; the most general result is that if no component of $\mathbb C_{\infty} - \Omega$ is a point, the Dirichlet problem is solvable

Answer (score 1):

In physics actually the Dirichlet problem works on Poisson equation in all the infinite void space free from conductors (Laplace equation), even though the infinite space is obviously unbonded provided that the electrostatic potential V approaches 0 as r approaches infinite at least as r^-1, so it is possibile to extend the Dirichlet problem to unbonded domain.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use the flux through an imaginary free surface as your boundary condition like neumann or just have the domain in the unbounded exterior. see for example the Raeder Tomultz Kritalovski solution for the evolution of the surface tension components of the stress tensor along the free boundary of a nuclear flow with time varying viscosities.